# UAC shield icon (BCM_SETSHIELD) not on a button

Tags: windows, winapi, uac, shell-icons

Following code adds a shield icon to a button:

```
SendMessage(btn1.Handle, BCM_SETSHIELD, 0, 1);
```

I've tried the same with checkboxes, radio button groups etc. Nothing works except a button.

Is there a way to add the shield icon to any other control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to add the shield icon to any other control?

If the control in question supports the display of a `HICON` (e. g. a static control), you can load the standard shield icon by calling [`LoadIconWithScaleDown`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775703(v=vs.85).aspx) with the `IDI_SHIELD` constant and assign that to the control.

```
int cx = GetSystemMetrics( SM_CXSMICON );
int cy = GetSystemMetrics( SM_CYSMICON );
HICON hShieldIcon = NULL;
HRESULT hr = LoadIconWithScaleDown( NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE( IDI_SHIELD ), cx, cy, 
                                    &hShieldIcon );
if( SUCCEEDED( hr ) )
{
    // Consult the reference on how to assign the HICON to the control.
}
```

If the control in question does not support assigning a `HICON`, you could use [custom-draw](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761817(v=vs.85).aspx), which is supported by many controls, to draw the icon yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775979.aspx) says:

> Sets the elevation required state for a specified button or command link to display an elevated icon.

This implies that the only supported controls are buttons and command links.